# Python Sklearn variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am learning sentiment analysis and I have a data frame of reviews, which I have to evaluate given a list of words, and get the weights assigned to those words. Unfortunately,  when I try to fit the regression I get the following error:
"ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [11, 133401]"

What am I missing on?
[CSV file](https://github.com/softporcupine/pandas-matplotlib-example/blob/master/amazon_baby.csv)

```
import pandas
import sklearn
import numpy as np 

products = pandas.read_csv('amazon_baby.csv')
selected_words=["awesome", "great", "fantastic", "amazing", "love", "horrible", "bad", "terrible", "awful", "wow", "hate"]

#ignore all 3* reviews
products = products[products['rating'] != 3]

#positive sentiment = 4* or 5* reviews
products['sentiment'] = products['rating'] >=4


#create a separate column for each word
for word in selected_words:
   products[word]=[len(re.findall(word,x)) for x in products['review'].tolist()]

# Define X and y
X = products[selected_words]
y = products['sentiment']

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

vect = CountVectorizer()

vect.fit(X_train)
X_train_dtm = vect.transform(X_train)
X_test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test)


from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train) #here is where I get the error
```

[image]

Comment: provide complete error message.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Added a screenshot. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CountVectorizer()` expects an iterable of strings and returns vectors that represents the counts of words. You already implemented this with the for loop and now trying to fit `CountVectorizer()` to counts of your selected words.

Assuming you want to just want to use your selected words as features

```
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

without the transformation will be fine.

Or if you would like to use all the words as features you could change your `X` to include the full review

```
X = products['review'].astype(str)
```

and then fit the `CountVectorizer()` and then use

```
logreg.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
```